# difficulties creating laravel projects

Tags: php

I got laravel 4, composer installed, PHP 5.4 and mcrypt running but typing the command:

```
$ php artisan serve 
Could not open input file: artisan
```

Any attempts to create a new project with command:

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist                         
  [RuntimeException]               
  The "-p" option does not exist.                                   
create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [package] [directory] [version]
```

I need help to work through my project please.

Comment: if you have installed laravel 4, then you need to be in laravel4 folder to start php artisan. Regarding composer I think becuae you write your-project-name you should give it a name like myproject1 with out "-"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name ~4.2.0 --prefer-dist
```

~4.2.0 means that you will get the latest version with 4.2.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you had not changed to laravel folder. It contains the artisan file. 
"Could not open input file" error came because it was not present in current directory.

You can try `php /var/www/laravel/artisan serve`

Here,
php is what you used to access this input file.

**Otherwise, change you directory** : `cd /var/www/laravel`

and then try again. Please report again if it didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be in the laravel project directory to use `php artisan serve`

You can follow this steps. It depends on your server.

`$ cd /path/to/laravel/project`

Then you can run
`php artisan serve` from here.

Go to browser and enter
`http://localhost:8000`

It should work now!